# PHP how can I store an array globally and query it in functions

Tags: php

I have an array, I want to store it once, it never needs to change. 
I want to have different functions for retrieving this information. I tried using a class but PHP doesn't let you store an array and values as an attribute you can just use. This is such a simple task, either I'm missing something or PHP can't do what I imagine is a simple task.

```
<?php

$questions = array();
$questions[0]['question'] = "How many legs does a spider have?";
$questions[0]['correct_answer'] = "8";
$questions[0]['answer'][0] = "8";
$questions[0]['answer'][1] = "7";
$questions[0]['answer'][2] = "6";
$questions[0]['answer'][3] = "5";
$questions[0]['answer'][4] = "4";
$questions[0]['answer'][5] = "3";
$questions[0]['answer'][6] = "2";
$questions[0]['answer'][7] = "1";
$questions[0]['answer'][8] = "0";
//Questions number 2
$questions[1]['question'] = "What do you put in a Hamburger bun?";
$questions[1]['correct_answer'] = "Hamburger";
$questions[1]['answer'][0] = "Lemons";
$questions[1]['answer'][1] = "Dog food";
$questions[1]['answer'][2] = "Pancakes";
$questions[1]['answer'][3] = "Hamburger";
$questions[1]['answer'][4] = "Flies";
$questions[1]['answer'][5] = "Mormons";
$questions[1]['answer'][6] = "H.P Lovecraft";
$questions[1]['answer'][7] = "A Space Man";
$questions[1]['answer'][8] = "Soup";
//Questions number 3
$questions[2]['question'] = "What is Obama's first name?";
$questions[2]['correct_answer'] = "Barack";
$questions[2]['answer'][0] = "Ludwig";
$questions[2]['answer'][1] = "Homer";
$questions[2]['answer'][2] = "Icarus";
$questions[2]['answer'][3] = "Mcenzie";
$questions[2]['answer'][4] = "Barack";
$questions[2]['answer'][5] = "David";
$questions[2]['answer'][6] = "Donald";
$questions[2]['answer'][7] = "Stewart";
$questions[2]['answer'][8] = "Lewis";
//Questions number 4
$questions[3]['question'] = "How long is a netflix trial?";
$questions[3]['correct_answer'] = "One Month";
$questions[3]['answer'][0] = "Eighteen Days";
$questions[3]['answer'][1] = "Two Weeks";
$questions[3]['answer'][2] = "One Year";
$questions[3]['answer'][3] = "Six Months";
$questions[3]['answer'][4] = "One Month";
$questions[3]['answer'][5] = "Ninty Days";
$questions[3]['answer'][6] = "One Day";
$questions[3]['answer'][7] = "12 Years";
$questions[3]['answer'][8] = "3 Lunar months";

function get_question_by_id($id){
    return $questions[$id];
}

?>
```

question_by_id should get the question the correct answer and all the possible answers of $questions[$id].

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Try creating a constant, since its never going to be changed

Comment: I understand the reason this is not working is because of scope. I get that. But I want to know how can I make this accessible without making it an even deeper dimensional array of $GLOBALS[questions']

Comment: @JonathanK I thought of that but const won't seem to let me work with 3-dimensional arrays. only array(1,2,3,4,5,6)

Comment: `function get_question_by_id($id, $questions){` and call it `get_question_by_id($id, $questions);`

Comment: Add `global` to function `get_question_by_id($id)`. That is 
`global  $questions`

Comment: To stop it having to put the array on the stack for each call do `function get_question_by_id($id, &$questions){`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need the array to be accessible to all the functions.

Comment: Then pass it as a parameter to all the functions

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I just declared it in a separate function and called get_questions I can call us the in_array function to search the return value. Post it as an answer and I'll close it off, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the $questions from the global scope first befor accessing them. Change your function to

```
function get_question_by_id($id){
    global $questions;
    return $questions[$id];
}
```

Or

```
function get_question_by_id($id, $questions){
    return $questions[$id];
}

// You then have to call it like this:
$question = get_question_by_id($id, $questions);
```

Comment: can I declare and set $questions outside of the function? That is my goal here.

Comment: Yes, with both examples I gave you, you can set them outside. I´d go with the second option.

Answer (score 0):

I just declared it in a separate function and called get_questions I can call us the in_array function to search the return value. Post it as an answer and I'll close it off, Getters and setters :) KISS method